# Multisite main theme changes do not show up in child sites

Tags: multisite

I have googled and not found an answer so maybe this is too basic.  I have a main site for a school blog, and will create a child site for each classroom.  I want each site to use the same basic template which is network-enabled.

When I add a header to the theme (as a super-admin), I expected the change to show up in the child sites since they use the same theme.

Using the above task as an example, do I really need to go to each child site and add the header separately?  Do I instead need to create a child theme in the main site?  In general, do any changes in the main theme show up automatically in the child sites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a multisite Installation each site is a single blog. It has its own contents and settings. If your change something in the backend of the main blog it does not have an effect on the other blog in the installation.
Only if you change something in the code of the theme, it will effect all blogs, which are using the theme, because all blog shares the source files.